# OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter closed session before database update

Tags: spring, jpa, transactions

I set up a OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter,but it always close session before writting to the database.here is my code ,please help me.Thank you .

```
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>panshi</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <description>服务器的参数！</description>
        <param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
        <param-value>webRoot.root</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring/*-config.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>



    <context-param>
        <description>日志的参数。</description>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/log/log4j.properties</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
      <listener>
    <listener-class>
      org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
    </listener-class>
  </listener>
    <!-- 
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/picshow/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>  
            <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/CSS/</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/images/</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.json</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>httpMethodFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>httpMethodFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>10</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
        <!-- Displays a stack trace -->
        <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/uncaughtException.jsp</location>
    </error-page>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>SetCharacterEncoding</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>SetCharacterEncoding</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>entityManagerFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>entityManagerFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>entityManagerFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.json</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
        <!-- 
        <filter>
    <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name> 
        <filter-class>  org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter </filter-class> 
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.json</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

JPA setting

```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="cn.hballSoft.domain" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="cn.hballSoft.security.domain" />

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close" p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
        p:url="${jdbc.url}" p:username="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}" />


    <!-- 这里多部分文件上传处理控制器 -->

    <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10000000" />
    </bean>

    <!-- JPA EntityManagerFactory -->
    <bean id="jpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />

    <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />

    <!-- JPA primary EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory-->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" lazy-init="true"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
        p:persistenceUnitName="ServerPU" p:jpaVendorAdapter-ref="jpaVendorAdapter"
        p:jpaDialect-ref="jpaDialect" p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" />
    <bean id="sessionFactory" factory-bean="entityManagerFactory"
        factory-method="getSessionFactory">
    </bean>



    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
        p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="departmentDao" class="cn.hballSoft.domain.dao.ImageDao"/>

    <bean id="userDAO" class="cn.hballSoft.security.domain.UserDAO"/>

    <bean id="roleDAO" class="cn.hballSoft.security.domain.RoleDAO"/>

    <bean id="resourceDAO" class="cn.hballSoft.security.domain.ResourceDAO">
        <qualifier value="resourceDAO"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

persistence

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">

    <persistence-unit name="ServerPU"
        transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <!-- RESOURCE_LOCAL -->
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <!--  <class>cn.hballSoft.domain.Category</class>-->
        <class>cn.hballSoft.security.domain.Resource</class>
        <class>cn.hballSoft.security.domain.Role</class>
        <class>cn.hballSoft.security.domain.User</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider" />
            <property name="hibernate.showsql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache"
                value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider"
                value="org.hibernate.search.store.FSDirectoryProvider" />
            <property name="hibernate.search.default.indexBase" value="d:/indexes" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

*************DAO***************

@Repository
    @Transactional
    public class ResourceDAO {

```
    public static final String TYPE = "type";

    @PersistenceContext
        private EntityManager entityManager;

        @Transactional
        public void save(Resource entity) {
            EntityManagerHelper.log("saving Resource instance", Level.INFO, null);
            try {
                entityManager.persist(entity);
                EntityManagerHelper.log("save successful", Level.INFO, null);
            } catch (RuntimeException re) {
                EntityManagerHelper.log("save failed", Level.ERROR, re);
                throw re;
            }
        }
}
```

*************method in the controller

```
 @Transactional
    @RequestMapping(value="/admin/manage/resource.json",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public LinkedHashMap<String, Object> createResource(@RequestBody Resource resource){
        Resource res = new Resource(resource.getResourceString());
        res.setDescn(resource.getDescn());
        res.setMethod(resource.getMethod());
        res.setType(resource.getType());
        res.setPriority(resource.getPriority());
        resourceDAO.save(res);
        if(!res.getId().isEmpty()){
        return  buildMessageResult(true,"成功建立资源"+res.getId());}
        else{
            return buildMessageResult(true,"建立资源失败！");
        }
    }
```

*******debug console output* **********************

```
 09-04 17:59:32 DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:220 - Looking up handler method for path /admin/manage/resource.json
 09-04 17:59:32 DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:264 - Found 1 matching mapping(s) for [/admin/manage/resource.json] : [{[/admin/manage/resource.json],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}]

 09-04 17:59:32 DEBUG HandlerMethod:135 - Method [initBinder] returned [null]
 09-04 17:59:32 DEBUG HandlerMethod:129 - Invoking [createResource] method with arguments [cn.hballSoft.security.domain.Resource@56ad4264]
 09-04 17:59:32  INFO ServerPU:60 - saving Resource instance
 09-04 17:59:32 DEBUG TransactionSynchronizationManager:140 - Retrieved value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@1a08777c] for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@529e0c79] bound to thread [http-8080-2]
 09-04 17:59:32 DEBUG AbstractSaveEventListener:130 - Generated identifier: 40288ae840e869000140e869a3f90000, using strategy: org.hibernate.id.UUIDHexGenerator
 09-04 17:59:32  INFO ServerPU:60 - save successful
 09-04 17:59:32 DEBUG HandlerMethod:135 - Method [createResource] returned [{Success=true, Message=成功建立资源40288ae840e869000140e869a3f90000}]
 09-04 17:59:32 DEBUG HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite:78 - Testing if return value handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ModelAndViewMethodReturnValueHandler@e58ff51] supports [java.util.LinkedHashMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>]
 09-04 17:59:32 DEBUG HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite:78 - Testing if return value handler [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelMethodProcessor@2b39d891] supports [java.util.LinkedHashMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>]
 09-04 17:59:32 DEBUG HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite:78 - Testing if return value handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ViewMethodReturnValueHandler@6b6b4e30] supports [java.util.LinkedHashMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>]
 09-04 17:59:32 DEBUG HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite:78 - Testing if return value handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor@59fcadd3] supports [java.util.LinkedHashMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>]
 09-04 17:59:32 DEBUG HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite:78 - Testing if return value handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.CallableMethodReturnValueHandler@31ccbefe] supports [java.util.LinkedHashMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>]
 09-04 17:59:32 DEBUG HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite:78 - Testing if return value handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.DeferredResultMethodReturnValueHandler@53e64a3b] supports [java.util.LinkedHashMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>]
 09-04 17:59:32 DEBUG HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite:78 - Testing if return value handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AsyncTaskMethodReturnValueHandler@70f87478] supports [java.util.LinkedHashMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>]
 09-04 17:59:32 DEBUG HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite:78 - Testing if return value handler [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor@f74f6ef] supports [java.util.LinkedHashMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>]
 09-04 17:59:32 DEBUG HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite:78 - Testing if return value handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor@47ffccd6] supports [java.util.LinkedHashMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>]
 09-04 17:59:32 DEBUG RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor:150 - Written [{Success=true, Message=成功建立资源40288ae840e869000140e869a3f90000}] as "application/json;charset=UTF-8" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter@34a8a271]
 09-04 17:59:32 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:999 - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'spring': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
 09-04 17:59:32 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:1028 - Cleared thread-bound request context: FirewalledRequest[ org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@40545646]
 09-04 17:59:32 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:966 - Successfully completed request
 09-04 17:59:32 DEBUG XmlWebApplicationContext:332 - Publishing event in WebApplicationContext for namespace 'spring-servlet': ServletRequestHandledEvent: url=[/panshi/admin/manage/resource.json]; client=[127.0.0.1]; method=[POST]; servlet=[spring]; session=[1AC287B1EBE796642F17B9AB4F9B6D8A]; user=[null]; time=[96ms]; status=[OK]
 09-04 17:59:32 DEBUG XmlWebApplicationContext:332 - Publishing event in Root WebApplicationContext: ServletRequestHandledEvent: url=[/panshi/admin/manage/resource.json]; client=[127.0.0.1]; method=[POST]; servlet=[spring]; session=[1AC287B1EBE796642F17B9AB4F9B6D8A]; user=[null]; time=[96ms]; status=[OK]
 09-04 17:59:32 DEBUG TransactionSynchronizationManager:243 - Removed value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@1a08777c] for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@529e0c79] from thread [http-8080-2]
 09-04 17:59:32 DEBUG OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter:188 - Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter
 09-04 17:59:32 DEBUG EntityManagerFactoryUtils:338 - Closing JPA EntityManager
 09-04 18:09:59 DEBUG HttpSessionEventPublisher:83 - Publishing event: org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionDestroyedEvent[source=org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@75f10df7]
 09-04 18:09:59 DEBUG XmlWebApplicationContext:332 - Publishing event in Root WebApplicationContext: org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionDestroyedEvent[source=org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@75f10df7]
 09-04 18:09:59 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:246 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl#0'
 09-04 18:09:59 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:246 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'loggerListener'
```

In the testcase , it works fine and write into the database well.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("jpa-config.xml")
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager="transactionManager", defaultRollback=false)
@Transactional
public class TestJPA {
    ApplicationContext ctx;
    DataSource dataSource;

        @BeforeTransaction
        public void verifyInitialDatabaseState() {
              ctx = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("E:/FBworkspace/panshi/WebContent/WEB-INF/spring/jpa-config.xml");
              dataSource = (DataSource)ctx.getBean("dataSource");
        }

        @Before
        public void setUpTestDataWithinTransaction() {
            // set up test data within the transaction
        }

        @Test
        // overrides the class-level defaultRollback setting
        @Rollback(false)
        public void modifyDatabaseWithinTransaction() {
               Resource res = new Resource("TEset REsource");
              ResourceDAO resDao = (ResourceDAO)ctx.getBean("resourceDAO"); 
              resDao.save(res);
        }

        @After
        public void tearDownWithinTransaction() {
            // execute "tear down" logic within the transaction
        }

        @AfterTransaction
        public void verifyFinalDatabaseState() {
            // logic to verify the final state after transaction has rolled back
        }

    }
```

*******************output with test* *********************

```
 09-04 18:44:05 DEBUG EntityManagerFactoryRegistry:66 - Registering EntityManagerFactory: ServerPU 
 09-04 18:44:05  WARN EntityManagerFactoryRegistry:80 - HHH000436: Entity manager factory name (ServerPU) is already registered.  If entity manager will be clustered or passivated, specify a unique value for property 'hibernate.ejb.entitymanager_factory_name'
 09-04 18:44:05  INFO ServerPU:60 - saving Resource instance
 09-04 18:44:05 DEBUG TransactionSynchronizationManager:140 - Retrieved value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@4b5a142f] for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@6e3404f] bound to thread [main]
[org.springframework.transaction.support.DefaultTransactionStatus@54eeabe8]; rollback [false]
 09-04 18:44:05 DEBUG JpaTransactionManager:923 - Triggering beforeCommit synchronization
 09-04 18:44:05 DEBUG JpaTransactionManager:936 - Triggering beforeCompletion synchronization
 09-04 18:44:05 DEBUG JpaTransactionManager:753 - Initiating transaction commit
 09-04 18:44:05 DEBUG JpaTransactionManager:508 - Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@62c37f31]
 09-04 18:44:05 DEBUG AbstractTransactionImpl:173 - committing
 09-04 18:44:05 DEBUG JdbcTransaction:113 - committed JDBC Connection
 09-04 18:44:05 DEBUG JdbcTransaction:126 - re-enabling autocommit

 09-04 18:44:05 DEBUG DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener:107 - After test method: context [[TestContext@2f8bbc98 testClass = TestJPA, testInstance = cn.hballSoft.test.TestJPA@6ba7508a, testMethod = modifyDatabaseWithinTransaction@TestJPA, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@3598cb3d testClass = TestJPA, locations = '{classpath:/cn/hballSoft/test/jpa-config.xml}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]]], class dirties context [false], class mode [null], method dirties context [false].
 09-04 18:44:05  INFO GenericApplicationContext:1042 - Closing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@4cf7c31d: startup date [Wed Sep 04 18:43:59 CST 2013]; root of context hierarchy
 09-04 18:44:05 DEBUG GenericApplicationContext:332 - Publishing event in org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@4cf7c31d: org.springframework.context.event.ContextClosedEvent[source=org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@4cf7c31d: startup date [Wed Sep 04 18:43:59 CST 2013]; root of context hierarchy]
 09-04 18:44:05 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:246 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'lifecycleProcessor'
 09-04 18:44:05  INFO DefaultListableBeanFactory:444 - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@62770d2e: defining beans 
 09-04 18:44:05 DEBUG DisposableBeanAdapter:226 - Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'
 09-04 18:44:05  INFO LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean:441 - Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'ServerPU'
 09-04 18:44:05 DEBUG SessionFactoryImpl:1369 - HHH000031: Closing
 09-04 18:44:05 DEBUG EntityManagerFactoryRegistry:108 - Remove: name=ServerPU
 09-04 18:44:05 DEBUG DisposableBeanAdapter:302 - Invoking destroy method 'close' on bean with name 'dataSource'
```

Answer (score 1):

I know what happen.
I have multiple *-config.xml
all of them have

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="cn.hballSoft.domain" />
<context:component-scan base-package="cn.hballSoft.security.domain" />
```

maybe it cause duplicate load transaction config.

keep single and slove the problem.